# Как конвертировать подобный формат времени?

Tags: c#

Как конвертировать такой формат времени `Sep 03 2022 10` (первое число - день, последнее - час) в `DateTime`?

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM dd yyyy HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`